# How to remove part of text after certain sign in bash

Tags: sed

I have .txt file which has following data:

```
user-5
user-10
user-12
user-23(some text)
user-11@dsa.dsd
user-23-sometext
```

I want to leave only `user-NUMBER`. So I have to remove text after `@`, `)` and second `-`.

I'm trying to use sed command, already succed with `@` and `)`. How can I remove text after second `-`?
My code: `sed 's/[)|@].*//g'`

Comment: `grep -o '^[^-]*-[0-9]*' file`?

Comment: With GNU awk: `awk 'NF=2' FS='[(@-]' file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's|\(user-[0-9]*\).*|\1|'
```

This way you don't need to include every possible character that would terminate a `user-NUMBER` match.